# Free up memory in azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database in Azure and there is currently 750GB of data in it.
In order to reduce the costs of running the database I want to keep it as small as possible and especially under 1TB.

The table let us call it "BigTable" which occupies 95% of the stored memory has the biggest share. More data will be stored in this database  every day and it is going on like that for four years. Data which is older than two years will be no longer needed. So this is what I already did:

1. I set up a second database "test_database" with point-in-time restore, did a backup for my database with the "Export" function and save it in blob storage. That worked fine.
2. I deleted the unnecessary the data with the tool SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) by running the statement:

```sql
Delete
From BigTable
Where Year(Date) < 2020
```

The Tool says 307 million datasets were deleted but the database gets bigger, around 870GB. I would say this stems from the fact that deletion will gets an entry in the log file so it gets bigger.

3. After that I executed this statement in SSMS:

```sql
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (0)
```

The actual result is portrait by the azure portal.
Used space as well as allocated space are over 750GB

So my question is: Why does not the database get smaller? And what can I do to actually shrink the size of the allocated space?

**Note after a few days:**
After a weekend I checked the azure portal again and it updated its values.
Now it says:
Used space: 486.86GB
Allocated space: 826.62GB
I wonder where that came from. And after that I executed the shrink command again. This time it worked. Maybe this is due to latency of the azure portal but I can't say that for sure.

Comment: Do you have some kind of cost management issue with the database size? Where exactly are you seeing the _still over 750GB of storage_ ? In the Azure portal?

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce the costs by reducing the database size. For now this is not an issue because it is still under 1TB but every day there will be more inserted and soon it will be bigger than 1 TB.

I just checked the Azure portal and it apparently now works the used space in Azure is now reduced but the allocated space is still over 750GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries-and-errors this is what I discovered:

When a delete statement will become effective in the sense of that the azure portal displays less used storage depends on the time set for "point-in-time-restore (PITR)".

If PITR is set to seven days it will keep the deleted data for seven days and only after seven days there will be a visible change in the used storage. So in order to see the result of an delete-statement quicker you have to set PITR to 1 day which also the minimum you can set it to.

After the deletion becomes effective only then it is useful to execute a "shrink-command" because only then there is actually something you can shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Because of a potential impact to database performance, Azure SQL Database does not automatically shrink data files. How to do it manually can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql#reclaim-unused-allocated-space)

Comment: I know that Azure SQL Database does not automatically shrink data files. Therefore I have already done it manually according to the documentation.